# How to fetch my follower's followers list using Instagram API

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, instagram, instagram-api

I have integrated latest API provided by Instagram for fetching my follower list. How can I fetch the list of followers of my follower. Does the Instagram API provide access to such information ?

Comment: a quick google search suggests it's  `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/followed-by?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`
 - per https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/relationships/#get_users_follows

Comment: I think @hanshenrik might mean `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/followed-by?access_t‌​oken=ACCESS-TOKEN` where user-id is the follower id from my follower list.

Comment: @danh ya i already used this api for my user id it is giving followers but for my follower user id it is giving bad access.

Comment: @vermamukesh do you get any solution for that?

Comment: @RobinsGupta no man we can not get this details in instagram.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instagram API **only** allows getting **your** followers/following data. You have to authenticate using `follower_list` permission scope to access this.

Before June 1st 2016, you were able to get any user's followers/following list, unfortunately this is no longer supported in the official Instagram API.